# How to extract strings from column in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, apply

I have a column that contains the names of the clients.
Now,I want to create another column which must contain only the following titles:
((Mr.),(Mrs),(Dr.))

My column is like :

```
print(df['Name'])

        Name
0 William, Mr. Henry
1 Mrs Meryam Hinadi
2 Dr. Richard Barodi
3 Yadar Danari Mr.
4 Gadi Dr. Nawsi
```

I defined this function, but it doesn't work properly. I must be missing somthing. please correct me.

```
def get_status(cols):
        name = cols[0]

        if name == name.str.contains('Mrs'):
            return 'Mrs'
        elif name == name.str.contains('Mr.'):
            return 'Mr.'
        elif name == name.str.contains('Dr.'):
            return 'Dr.'
        else:
            return name

df['Titles'] = df['Name'].apply(get_status)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_status(cols):
    if ('Mrs') in cols:
        return 'Mrs'
    elif ('Mr.') in cols:
        return 'Mr.'
    elif ('Dr.') in cols:
        return 'Dr.'
    else:
        return cols

df['Titles'] = df['name'].apply(get_status)
```

Output:

```
    name               Titles
0   William, Mr. Henry  Mr.
1   Mrs Meryam Hinadi   Mrs
2   Dr. Richard Barodi  Dr.
3   Yadar Danari Mr.    Mr.
4   Gadi Dr. Nawsi      Dr.
```

Comment: I got this error :RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object --> but I correct it by changing (return name) by return cols. Maybe you should edit your answer.